# linux вопрос по патчингу ядра

Tags: linux, kernel

У меня есть специализированная версия ядра `linux` версии *3.16.6*. В ней имеется определенный баг, которого нет в обычных версиях ядра *3.16.6-2* и *3.18.1* (к специализированности ядра отношения не имеет).
Мне нужно улучшить специализированное ядро хотя бы до версии *3.16.6-2*, чтобы попытаться избавиться от бага, но при этом сохранить его специализированность (то есть я не могу просто взять исходники соответствующей версии и собрать, т.к. моей компетенции не хватит на то, чтобы повторить все специальные настройки и тюнинг, сделанные командой опытных профи, которые не торопятся с выпуском собственных обновленных релизов).
Насколько я знаю, мне нужно выполнить инкрементальный патч, который сделает в специальной версии ядра те изменения, которые актуализируют ее к состоянию *3.17.1* (например). Также я знаю, что патчи типа **rc** - не инкрементальные, а базируются на какой-то старой версии. Я не ошибаюсь с этим? И как мне убедиться в том, что патч, который я, возможно, найду, именно того типа, что нужен мне?
[Здесь](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/incr/) я не очень разобрался по той причине, что в списке нет версии, например, 3.16.6-2, которая, по утверждениям моей openSUSE, используется в ней. То есть список, выходит, не полон или что-то еще, что вносит неопределенность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

«все специальные настройки и тюнинг», скорее всего, исчерпываются содержимым файла `.config`, лежащим в корне дерева исходников.

также обычно конфигурация выполняющейся в данный момент программы *linux* доступна по адресу `/boot/config-$(uname -r)`.

также она может быть доступна в сжатом виде в псевдо-файловой системе `/proc` (если программа собрана с такой опцией) по адресу `/proc/config.gz` или что-нибудь в этом духе (посмотрите вывод команды `ls /proc/config*`).

---

как им воспользоваться?

1. распакуйте исходники нужной вам версии программы *linux* и «перейдите» в получившийся каталог:

   ```
   $ tar -xf архив.с.исходниками
   $ cd получившийся.каталог
   ```
2. скопируйте текущую конфигурацию любым из трёх подходящих вариантов:

   ```
   $ cp /путь/к/исходникам/текущего/ядра/.config .config
   $ cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
   $ zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
   ```
3. выполните:

   ```
   $ make olddefconfig
   ```
4. а дальше, как и обычно, по инструкциям, имеющимся в тысячах экземпляров по всему интернету, что-то вроде: `make; sudo make modules_install install`.

   хотя, конечно, более верно будет следовать дистрибутивно-рекомендуемым инструкциям.

Comment: Я надеялся на то, что тюнинг TinyCor'овского ядра заключается только в конфиге, но надо еще все-таки уточнить у команды мейнтейнеров. Если так, то, по сути, я могу взять любое ядро, хоть самое новое, и применить к нему старый конфиг (за исключением каких-то маловероятных ситуаций, когда версия претерпела такие изменения, что к ней не применим старый конфигурационный файл?). Это было бы очень удобно.

Comment: файл вполне будет применим: загляните в него — это ведь просто присвоения значений переменным. неактуальные переменные просто ни на что не повлияют, а отсутствующим переменным будет назначено дефолтное значение (см. третий шаг: если вы укажете цель **oldconfig**, то получите сотни вопросов о том, что присваивать той или иной *новой* переменной, которой нет в старом конфиге)

Comment: *но надо еще все-таки уточнить* — уточните, конечно. может быть, они накладывают патчи, которые до сих пор не вошли в основную ветку программы. впрочем, если эти патчи не приняли в основную ветку, остаётся интересный вопрос: а стоит ли их использовать вообще? ну, тут уж вам выбирать.

Comment: если процесс мэйнтэйнинга linux-а у них не сильно отличается от принятого в других дистрибутивах, то патчи они, действительно, накладывают, **бэкпортируя** их из более новых версий в ту, поддержкой которой и занимаются. в таком случае *совсем новая* версия исходников **уже** содержит все эти патчи.

Comment: Они могли накладывать патчи, которые делают из обычного ядра специализированное. То есть, в них заключается вся специфика Tiny Core: загрузка всего системного функционала (кроме busybox) из архивных модулей .tcz, соответственно каждый раз новая, чистая система работающая сугубо в RAM, персистентность только в папке /home, префикс установки /usr/local вместо /usr и прочее.

Comment: Нет, вряд ли они бэкпортируют современные патчи. Скорее всего, они взяли за основу какую-то более-менее стабильную версию из середнячков и с тех пор не особо торопятся с актуализацией.

Comment: *загрузка всего системного функционала* — то, что вы написали, начиная с этих слов, к программе linux не имеет никакого отношения. этим занимается операционная система. linux всего лишь запускает init-процесс в userspace, который и производит необходимые манипуляции.

Comment: скорее всего, в вашем дистрибутиве используется т.н. initrd-образ, т.е. сжатый образ «стартовой» корневой файловой системы. initrd дожен перестраиваться под каждую версию установленной программы linux, т.к. обычно содержит, в том числе, и подгружаемые в ядерное адресное пространство модули. сами модули собираются в процессе сборки linux-а. для формирования initrd обычно используется программа mkinitrd, но тут может быть и своя дистрибутивная обёртка — уточните в документации дистрибутива.

Comment: <<If you compile a new kernel, you need to compile all the modules you need.
Some packages depend on extensions that are named after the kernel version.
You will need to create all these packages too.>>

Comment: @JacenKaedus, это не имеет отношения к сборке initrd. хотя под «some packages», возможно и подразумевается (в том числе) и пакет с initrd. ну, если в вашем дистрибутиве его (initrd) принято пакетировать.